# Display fields from dataSet over imported image

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, report

My asp.net app uses Crystal Reports to display certain data from database, and one of those report is a License Card. How can I display DataSet fields over the image, if I even can?

I opened my report and right clicked insert -> picture and I inserted this template. I'm unable to actually drag fields onto the image, they appear to be covered up.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to push the image to backgroud try like this:

you can go to report explorer and `right the image --> Move --> backward`

or

on desing itself `right the image --> Move --> backward`

Comment: acctualy it is Right the image --> move --> to back, but we can consider this as answer! thank you man!